# How to make dynamic consecutive numbers in one column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a list of bills. I must continuously name them according to my bank accounts.

Normally I would sort my sheet by BANK ACCOUNT and DATE, then tag the NUMBER COLUMN by using the "blue square", and after that, I sort by date again.

I wanna program a script function to iterate through the column NUMBER which defines and read the ACCOUNT column and tag the NUMBER row accordingly.
I thought I make a "settings"-column somewhere to define the look of the "auto-formatter":

IF BANK {YY}-BANK-{NUMBER}
   IF CASH {YY}-CASH-{NUMBER}

In the end, it should look like the example below:

```
 DATE   NUMBER       ACCOUNT
|------|------------|-------|
 1. Jan  18-CASH-01   CASH
 1. Jan  18-BANK-01   BANK
 2. Jan  18-CASH-02   CASH
 3. Jan  18-CASH-03   CASH
 4. Jan  18-BANK-02   BANK
```

I made a demo sheet that is free to change or clone.
The basic formula is implemented.
Only the formula to iterate is missing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aJRqODUMyJai-aVyTj3_konvc8qpL8idKEHNCs9cxSo/edit?usp=sharing

Has anyone a suggestion or starting point for me?
I am not good at google sheets API.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be done with a formula? In F1 I entered

```
={"Format"; ArrayFormula(if(len(D2:D), text(C2:C7, "yy")&"-"& UPPER(D2:D)&"-"&iferror(SORT(ROW(D2:D),SORT(ROW(D2:D),D2:D,1),1)-MATCH(D2:D,SORT(D2:D),0)-ROW()+1),))}
```

See if that works for you?

EDIT, to match the names of the backaccounts to a range, use vlookup

```
={"Solution A"; ArrayFormula(if(len(D2:D), text(C2:C7, "yy")&"-"& 
VLOOKUP(D2:D, SETTINGS!A10:C, 2, 0)&"- 
"&iferror(SORT(ROW(D2:D),SORT(ROW(D2:D),D2:D,1),1)- 
MATCH(D2:D,SORT(D2:D),0)-ROW()+1),))}
```

Comment: WoW!!! It works out of the box! Thank you! But I still have trouble to fit your solution with my "settings"-sheet. In reality, I am determined to a specific name in my "Bill Type"-column and wanna be able to rename that accordingly from my "settings"-page. For example: instead of "PAYPAL" it must be renamed as "PP". "Bank Account Company" must be renamed to "BANK1". I hope you understand? is that also possible with your "oneliner"? Or must that be done with a function? Thank you again!

Comment: Edited my post. Please note that selecting 'type' in col D will return error because it is not in the vlookup range in settings.

Comment: AWESOME!  I can't believe that you fixed that in lightning speed (I am sitting here since hours ).  Thank you so much!

Comment: ehm.. maybe you can have a look through my "original sheet" (not the demo). I renamed all demo ranges to variables, which are matching exactly to that in my original sheet. I kept all relations the same. but somehow my original one is telling me only "Formula parse error." There are only these two vars and that one column. I dont understand why that is happening. :-( I will delete this link after a solution was found... ORIGINAL: Everything is in "Einstellungen" (settings) and "A->A3" sheet... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAJFDs6tpkiJXVTkv7NO7vsdT0LjOSxAsU2oBiM_SN4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't access that spreadsheet, but if your spreadsheet locale is set to Germany you should replace the comma's in the formula with semi-colons (;). I changed the locale in the spreadsheet you shared so you could copy the formula from there.

Comment: Its in english... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAJFDs6tpkiJXVTkv7NO7vsdT0LjOSxAsU2oBiM_SN4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206985/discussion-between-jan-and-jpv).